# Pymongo: Best way to remove $oid in Response

Tags: pymongo, pymongo-3.x, flask-pymongo

I have started using Pymongo recently and now I want to find the best way to remove $oid in Response

When I use `find`:

```
result = db.nodes.find_one({ "name": "Archer" }
```

And get the response:

```
json.loads(dumps(result))
```

The result would be:

```
{
  "_id": {
  "$oid": "5e7511c45cb29ef48b8cfcff"
  },
  "about": "A jazz pianist falls for an aspiring actress in Los Angeles."
}
```

My expected:

```
{
  "_id": "5e7511c45cb29ef48b8cfcff",
  "about": "A jazz pianist falls for an aspiring actress in Los Angeles."
}
```

As you seen, we can use:

```
resp = json.loads(dumps(result))
resp['id'] = resp['id']['$oid']
```

But I think this is not the best way. Hope you guys have better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of aggregation:

```
result = db.nodes.aggregate([{'$match': {"name": "Archer"}}
                             {'$addFields': {"Id": '$_id.oid'}},
                             {'$project': {'_id': 0}}])
data = json.dumps(list(result))
```

Here, with `$addFields` I add a new field `Id` in which I introduce the value of `oid`. Then I make a projection where I eliminate the `_id` field of the result. After, as I get a cursor, I turn it into a list.

It may not work as you hope but the general idea is there.

Comment: When I use you code, the `id` field completely disappear :(

Comment: What if you do this: `{'$addFields': {"Id": '$_id.$oid'}}` ?

Comment: Also disappear, bro. Remember I am using `Pymongo`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there's no `$oid` in the response. What you are seeing is the python driver represent the `_id` field as an ObjectId instance, and then the `dumps()` method represent the the ObjectId field as a string format. the `$oid` bit is just to let you know the field is an ObjectId should you need to use for some purpose later.

The next part of the answer depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve. Almost certainly you can acheive it using the result object without converting it to JSON.

If you just want to get rid of it altogether, you can do :

```
result = db.nodes.find_one({ "name": "Archer" }, {'_id': 0})
print(result)
```

which gives:

```
{"name": "Archer"}
```

Comment: Thanks Belly for the instruction. Exactly I don't want to get rid of the `_id` field like you said. I want to find the best way to map the `$oid` value to `_id` field in the response. So how can I get the expected result?

Comment: I'll come back to my point ... why do you want to do this? To make it look pretty? What purpose is there to have it as a bit of JSON rather than have it as a nice result object primed to do whatever you need?

Comment: I just simply want the json look prettier for frontend team. I wonder if is it good?

Comment: `_id`s aren't the prettiest of things anyway. If that is your aim, then your original approach is as good as any..

Comment: I got it, maybe I will get rid of `_id` because the unnecessariness. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I am using some form of custom handler. I managed to remove `$oid` and replace it with just the id string:

```
# Custom Handler
def my_handler(x):
    if isinstance(x, datetime.datetime):
        return x.isoformat()
    elif isinstance(x, bson.objectid.ObjectId):
        return str(x)
    else:
        raise TypeError(x)

# parsing
def parse_json(data):
    return json.loads(json.dumps(data, default=my_handler))

result = db.nodes.aggregate([{'$match': {"name": "Archer"}}
                             {'$addFields': {"_id": '$_id'}},
                             {'$project': {'_id': 0}}])
data = parse_json(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

def remove_oid(string):
    while True:
        pattern = re.compile('{\s*"\$oid":\s*(\"[a-z0-9]{1,}\")\s*}')
        match = re.search(pattern, string)
        if match:
            string = string.replace(match.group(0), match.group(1))
        else:
            return string

string = json_dumps(mongo_query_result)
string = remove_oid(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second argument of `find_one`, you can define which fields to exclude, in the following way:

```
site_information = mongo.db.sites.find_one({'username': username}, {'_id': False})
```

This statement will exclude the '_id' field from being selected from the returned documents.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your result to below function.
(Tested at 5 level of nesting with $oid and $data)

```
def remove_special_fields(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        new_dict = {}
        for key, value in d.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict) and ('$oid' in value or '$date' in value):
                new_dict[key] = value.get('$oid', value.get('$date'))
            else:
                new_dict[key] = remove_special_fields(value)
        return new_dict
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        return [remove_special_fields(item) for item in d]
    else:
        return d
```